# How Do I Search For An Aritfactory Build Artifact Based On Environment Name?

Tags: artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

The Build Info JSON for my build in Artifactory contains this:

```
{
"properties": {
    "java.vendor": "Oracle Corporation",
    "sun.java.launcher": "SUN_STANDARD",
    "sun.management.compiler": "HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers",
    "buildInfo.env.CLASSPATH": "",
    "os.name": "Linux",
    "buildInfo.env.GIT_BRANCH": "origin/my-branch-name",
},
"version": "1.0.1",
"name": "my-project",
"number": "359",
```

I want to use [AQL](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-SEARCHES) to [search](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+Query+Language) for artifacts created from a specific branch name.

If I search with the project name and build number I get results.

```
items.find({
  "@build.name":"my-project",
  "@build.number":"359"
}).include("*")
```

However, if I try to search within the properties I don't.

```
items.find({
  "@build.properties.buildInfo.env.GIT_BRANCH": "origin/my-branch-name"
}).include("*")
```

How do I search within these properties? i.e. the environment variables of the build.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do something like

```
items.find({
  "item.artifact.module.build.properties.@buildInfo.env.GIT_BRANCH" : {"$eq" : "origin/my-branch-name"}}
})
```

Comment: Yeah that's why I said 'something *like*' -- wrote from the top of my head...   this will work: ```curl -XPOST "http://localhost:8080/artifactory/api/search/aql" -uadmin:password -H "Content-Type: text/plain" -d 'items.find({"artifact.module.build.@buildInfo.env.GIT_BRANCH" : {"$eq" : "origin/my-branch-name"}})'
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't return anything. Maybe because you are not referencing the properties? It would be better to edit the answer than add new answers in the comments though.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of searching the build info I decided to modify jenkins to add the GIT_BRANCH as a build property.

I can now search like this:

```
items.find({
    "@build.name":"my-project",
    "@build.branch":{"$match":"*my-branch-name*"},
    "name":{"$match":"*.tar.gz"}
}).include("*")
```

Comment: how did you add `GIT_BRANCH` in Jenkins?

Comment: I can't remember off the top of my head and I don't have access to this instance anymore. However, I believe it is added automatically with the git plugin.

Comment: ah, so you added something like `props="vcs.Branch=${GIT_BRANCH}"` to your upload spec then. I see. Thanks!